# CSS Media query: to second row depending on screen width

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a div with following elements

```
<div>
    <a class="postLink" href="{{post.authorLink}}"  target="_blank">{{post.author}}</a>
    <span class="">Published: {{ post.published}}</span>
    <a class="postLink" href="{{post.link}}"  target="_blank">View More</a>
</div>
```

Normally this is rendered as:

```
{{post.author}}   Published: {{ post.published}}   View More
```

When screen is smaller than, for example 760px, how can I move all links to second line?

```
Published: {{ post.published}}   
{{post.author}}   View More
```

Comment: `@media (max-width: 760px){ div > * {display: block} }` will move any direct/immediate `div` child to next line, but maybe you prefer something else?

Comment: @skobaljic: That takes of the display style but the op wishes to rerrange the content?

Comment: Aff, true.. that is now an interesting question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably use relative position on container, then absolute for span in media query. But I find this way more interesting:

```css
.postInfo a {
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.postPublished::after {
    content: attr(data-published);
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 780px) {
    .postPublished::after {
        display: none;
    }
    .postPublished::before {
        content: attr(data-published);
        display: block;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="postInfo">
    <span class="postPublished" data-published="Published: {{ post.published}}">
        <a  class="postLink" href="{{post.authorLink}}"  target="_blank">{{post.author}}</a>
    </span>
    <a class="postLink" href="{{post.link}}" target="_blank">View More</a>
</div>
```

Check it [on Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m9n4fuwf/).